# adding multiple jlabels at a specific position each time a jbutton is pressed

Tags: dynamic, jlabel

```
private void btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           JLabel label=new JLabel("test label");
           label.setBounds(0,0,135,14);
           panel.add(label);
           panel.repaint();  

        }
    });

}
```

i want to add each label at a specific position in the panel like adding records to a table(suppose table has 4 columns). how to achieve that.

Comment: Use a proper layout manager, e.g. grid layout. If you are doing it with null layout, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: actually i am new to java. can u provide me any link or write a little code to explain @ Coderino Javarino